cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 30016 milliseconds with 0 bytes
I am developing a Laravel application that implements OAuth2 for authentication. When attempting to log in and retrieve an access token using the password grant type, I encounter the following error during the request to the token endpoint.
public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $customer = Customer::where('username', $request->username)->first();


        $oClient = OClient::where('password_client', 1)->first();
        if (!$oClient) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'failed',
                'message' => 'OAuth client not found',
                'code' => 400
            ], 400);
        }

        $response = Http::asForm()->post('http://localhost:8000/oauth/token', [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => $oClient->id,
            'client_secret' => $oClient->secret,
            'username' => $request->username,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'provider' => 'customers',
            'scope' => '*',
        ]);

        if ($response->successful()) {
            $tokens = $response->json();
            return response()->json([
                'access_token' => $tokens['access_token'],
                'refresh_token' => $tokens['refresh_token'],
            ]);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'failed',
                'message' => $response->json('error_description', 'Unknown error'),
                'code' => $response->status(),
            ], $response->status());
        }
    }

When I test the function by API on Postman, I get this error. How I can solve it?
{
  "status": "failed",
  "message": "cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 30016 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://localhost:8000/oauth/token",
  "code": 400
}


Given that the server is running on port 8000 I'm going to assume that you're using PHP's built-in webserver. You should know that this webserver can handle exactly one connection at a time, so making a request back to itself will always be blocked and time out. I do not recommend using php -S for anything more than the most basic functional test at most, or at all if possible.
